# How to preform operation which returns single for each element of list returned by observable and return it as a list?

Tags: rx-java2

The question is quite complicated but in code seems to look simpler (I hope)

I have a functions like bellow

```
fun trackFoos(): Observable<List<Foo>> {/*....*/}
fun getBarForFoo(fooState: Foo.State): Single<Bar>
```

And I was having some code which is bound to other parts of apps so I cannot change it too much.

```
Observable.combineLatest(
              trackFoos(),
              Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS),
              BiFunction() {foos: List<Foo>, _:Long -> foos}
             ).subscribe { foos -> /*....*/ }
```

And now I need to pass also object of Bar for each foo object using this `getBarForFoo`

So I need to write  `trackPairOfFooAndBar()` using `trackFoos()` and `getBarForFoo()` to use it as below:

```
Observable.combineLatest(
              trackPairOfFooAndBar(),
              Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS),
              BiFunction() {fooBarList: List<Pair<Foo,Bar>>, _:Long -> fooBarList}
             ).subscribe { fooBarList-> /*....*/ }
```

I saw this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47676208/1461568 but there is assumption that second call is observable (I have Single)

So how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

1. Transform `trackFoos()` from `Observable<List<Foo>>` to `Observable<Foo>`
2. For each `Foo` do `getBarForFoo()` and map result so it really returns `Pair<Foo, Bar>`
3. (Optional) If you need `Single<List<Pair<Foo,Bar>>>` you can just call `toList()`
4. (Optional) If you really need `Observable` then you can just call `toObservable()`

In code:

```
fun trackPairOfFooAndBar() : Observable<Pair<Foo, Bar>> {
    return trackFoos()            
            .flatMapIterable { it } // or flatMap {list -> Observable.fromIterable(list)}
            .flatMapSingle { foo -> getBarForFoo(foo.state).map { foo to it } }
            // optional, depending what is the final signature that you want
            //.toList().toObservable 
}
```

Comment: thx. I will check. I really need to observe the result. App has to update UI if any of Foos changed.