# flatmap does not work v.s. foreach in RxJava

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

I am trying to fetch a list of strings from API_1 (`getList()`), then iterate through each string in the list and make another API_2(`syncData()`) network call by each datatype string, somehow I don't understand why the code below can make second calls with `forEach()` but not `flatMap()`.

**flatMap() Version:**

```
Observable.just(getListNetworkCall())
                .flatMapIterable(response -> response.getDataList())
                .flatMap(dataType -> syncData(dataType))
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe(new Consumer<Response2>() {
                    @Override
                    public void accept(Response2 response) throws Throwable {
                        System.out.println("response:" + response.toString());
                    }
                });
```

**forEach() Version:**

```
Observable.just(getList())
               .flatMapIterable(response -> response.getDataList())
               .forEach(dataType -> syncData(dataType));
```

---

```
private Observable<Response2> syncData(String dataType) {
        return Observable.just(syncDataNetworkCall(dataType));
}
```

What I saw in the `flatMap() Version` is that it did the getList() call only. Am I missing any piece of knowledge on RxJava, I also take reference on [RxJava Combine Sequence Of Requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47641605/rxjava-combine-sequence-of-requests)

Thanks.

Comment: One difference is that the *flatMap* method is using `Schedulers.io()` which can affect the order of execution. Try either adding `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())` to *forEach* method or removing scheduler from *flatMap* method and see if you can get the same behavior from both methods

Comment: What is the execution order you mentioned affected by `flatMap()`, are you saying the emitting items(Response2) or something else?

Comment: I remove the `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())` from `flatMap() Version`, and it did perform the `syncData()` calls inside the _.flatmap_ operator. Can you explain why?  Also I don't think I can add anything except `dispose()` after forEach()

Comment: `Schedulers.io()` will make the stream run on another thread. This means that the calling thread will not wait for `syncData(dataType)` call to complete. If you remove scheduler, it will run on the calling thread so the calling thread will wait until all `syncData` complete. If you want to add `.subscribeOn` in the *forEach* version, you can put it just before `.forEach` operator. In fact it doesn't really matter in which order you call `.subscribeOn` you can put it anywhere in the chain.

Comment: That syncData method contains code executing right at the invocation inside `flatMap` and its result is wrapped into a `just` Observable. This is a common misunderstanding about Rx as `just` takes a constant reference and doesn't defer any calculation.

Comment: @SanlokLee Thank you for your answers. I also took a look `forEach()` https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Blocking-Observable-Operators so I understand why forEach works instead at the very first beginning.

Comment: @akarnokd Thank you for your answer and pointing out I have a misunderstanding on the Rx!